# iframe full width keeps expanding width

Tags: iframe, width

im trying to use an iframe in a div next to other div but, instead of getting full width it gets a larger width, so you have to scroll to see it, and it is above all the website.

Here is an example of whats happening, what should i do?

here is my divs

```
<div class="izquierda"></div>
<div class="derecha">
  <iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/DL67BuPR2PQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>


</div>
```

this is my css

```
body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;

}

.contenedor {
  width:100%;


}

.izquierda {
  width:200px;
  height:100%;
  position:absolute;
  background-color:green;

}

.derecha {
  width:100%;
  left:200px;
  background-color:#09b;
  height:100%;
  position:absolute;



}


iframe {

  width:100%;
max-height:100%;

}
```

http://jsbin.com/sipumofu/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

Remove The width: 100%; in your css in iframe, this will cause the iframe to expand as wide as the div.

If you want to increase the with of the iframe increase the width in the iframe tag as in the example given below

```
<iframe width="700" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/DL67BuPR2PQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Otherwise reduce the width of your div .derecha in your css